# Does $\mathbb{E}[g(X)Y]=0$ for all functions $g$ imply $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation

Is there any result saying something like
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)Y]=0 \,\,\forall g\in\mathcal{G}\,\,\,\implies\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]=0$$
where $\mathcal{G}$ is some function class? Have been searching online but didn't find anything useful.

Context: I came across a paper where the objective function is of the form $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)\mid X]=0$  but the authors instead use $\mathbb{E}[g(X)(X-Y)]=0$ for a class of $g\in\mathcal{G}$ in their actual implementation. I understand the reason is to avoid the conditional moment and replace it by the unconditional one, but are the two moments equivalent (the if direction is easy to show so I'm wondering the other direction...)?

Comment: The statement is true if the class $\mathcal{G}$ is rich enough to approximate any bounded measurable functions. Examples include the family of bounded continuous functions, or the family of the indicator functions of Borel measurable sets, etc.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the comment! I vaguely recall something like that... Do you have a reference to this that you could possibly share?